# Using Multiple Foreign Keys to the same table in LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table Users and a table Items

In the Items table, I have fields such as

ModifiedBy
CreatedBy
AssignedTo

which all have a userId integer. The database is set up to have these as foreign keys back to the Users table.

When using LINQToSQL, the relationships which are automatically built from the dbml end up giving me names like User, User1 and User2

e.g. myItem.User1.Name or myItem.User2.Name

Obviously this isn't very readable and I'd like it be along the lines of

myItem.CreatedByUser.Name or myItem.ModifiedByUser.Name etc

I could change the names of the relationships but that means I have to redo that every time I change the db schema and refresh the dbml.

Is there any way round this?

Comment: http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/petar/Blog/archive/2008/01/29/multi-field-foreign-key-relationship-to-the-same-database-table-and-linq.aspx

This blog mentions the same problem but the solution isn't right for me as I'm constantly changing my db schema and don't want to have to do a lot of manual stuff every time I change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer: No.

Someone has suggested the idea of creating partial Association classes where the property names get defined, but that won't work either: [Renaming LINQ 2 SQL Entity Properties Through Partial Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741898/renaming-linq-2-sql-entity-properties-through-partial-classes).

Your choice is to either spend a little time learning more about LINQ-to-SQL "behind-the-scenes" so that you can manually make the necessary modifications or to just change the property names through the Properties window. Personally, I just delete/redrag/rename, because not setting a property correctly is a pain to debug because the exceptions that get thrown give you little to no clue as to what caused it. I even went so far as to create a unit test library that takes each MetaTable object in the model and verifies the field count, the ServerDataType contents of each field, the association count, the names of each association, and the names of each end of the association. Every few changes, I run the unit tests to make sure that the model is intact.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, no... the names are created based on the second table in the relationship.

But what you should know is that you don't have to "refresh" (meaning, delete the table in the DBML then re-drag-and-drop it).

For the project I'm working on, we have over 200 tables... about 50 of which we have manually tweaked after dragging them from the database. We *never* delete and re-drag tables as there have been so many changes post-auto-generation.

Comment: For me, it's preferable to delete and redrag because, at least, the application of the changes are consistent based on the SqlMetal engine.  I'd rather use the Properties window to change a couple of names rather than miss setting an AutoSync property, because the exceptions that get thrown give you very little clue as to how to resolve it.

Comment: To each his own :) ... it's not a perfect system (LINQ to SQL that is), so whatever is easiest for you is really the answer. We did it the same way as you, but eventually it got out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

I just add a small partial class to extend the object with suitably named properties, example below:

```
namespace Database.TableModels {
    partial class WTSR_Induction {
        public EmailTemplate ConfirmationEmailTemplate {
            get { return EmailTemplate1; }
        }
        public EmailTemplate InviteEmailTemplate {
            get { return EmailTemplate; }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the `WTSR_Inductions` table has two links to the `EmailTemplates` table, hence the `EmailTemplate` and `EmailTemplate1` properties.

Comment: It's kind of ugly but probably the best solution in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but you can do this by selecting the relationship on the linq model and  go to properties and update the parent property name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use linq to sql without the [dbml](http://blogs.msdn.com/spike/archive/2010/01/08/how-to-use-linq-to-sql-without-using-the-designer-generated-classes.aspx) it may be extra work upfront but from the perspective of a change to a table column name it may be easier than changes to the dbml as you have described.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating extension methods mapping the names you want to the names you get from the autogenerated code. That way after each auto-generation you don't have to change the autogenerated code, but only your own extension methods. That, plus the unit tests to do sanity checks as suggested elsewhere on this page should work fine.

I have just faced this problem myself and I'm off to try to implement my own suggestion.

EDIT: This seems relevant: 
[SQLMetal Multiple Foreign Keys Pointing to One Table Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736003/sqlmetal-multiple-foreign-keys-pointing-to-one-table-issue)